# (Java) Reading in a file, storing string information into an array, and writing a variation of this string out

Tags: java, arrays

This question has had me working for hours so I would immensely appreciate any help. I need to read in a file through command line argument that contains name, major, ID, and graduation date of  multiple students. Then, I need to store this information in an array, and use this array to output just the information of specific students that satisfy a condition (they will graduate in 2017). So essentially I'm outputting a new file that only contains students that match this condition.

I've created this code to read in a file and store them to an array. But from here, I am stumped :(

Please, any help would be valuable.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.io.File;

public class Aid {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {


        String token1 = "";

        Scanner inFile1 = new Scanner(new File("location of file in my folder")).useDelimiter(",\\s*");


        List<String> temps = new ArrayList<String>();

        while (inFile1.hasNext()) {
           token1 = inFile1.next();
           temps.add(token1);
        }
        inFile1.close();

        String[] tempsArray = temps.toArray(new String[0]);

        for (String s : tempsArray) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you required to answer it in that form? you should use a split instead of stringtokenzier.
To read from a file for simplicities sake,

Create an arrayList of type String so you can resize as needed.

```
<ArrayList>String info = new <ArrayList>String();
```

Create a File object.
    File thisFile = new File(*The name of the file being read goes*)

Create your scanner. 
`Scanner scanThis = new Scanner(thisFile);`

```
while(scanThis.hasNext())
{
String str = scanThis.next();
info.add(str);
}
```

Ive only been programming for 2 weeks or so, feel free to correct me if im wrong ill actually go test this myself ;)

Comment: Ok to output to a file you need PrintWriter hold up ill see if i can make a quick file

Answer (score 0):

Adding another answer because it might be difficult to read from the comments

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
/**
 * Write a description of class Other here.
 * 
 * @author (your name) 
 * @version (a version number or a date)
 */
public class Other 
{
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
File myFile = new File("Users/josephcrachiolo/Desktop/ReadThis.txt"); //Create a file object and hold the name of our file.
Scanner readThis = new Scanner(myFile); //Scanner object to read from the file
ArrayList<String> temp = new ArrayList<String>(); arraylist for the purpose of resizing array
StringTokenizer stok; //Not needed i believe
PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter("Yalla.txt"); //create a printwriter object so we can write to the specified file "Yalla.txt"
int i = 0; //Used as incrementor

while(readThis.hasNext()) //while the file has something to be read
{
String str = readThis.next(); //Here will read each peice of text and will seperate by spaces
//stok = new StringTokenizer(str) --> possibly not needed
temp.add(str); //add to the arraylist object //add that text into our arraylist
}
while(!temp.isEmpty()) //while our arraylist is not empty execute
{
output.print(temp.get(i)); //print to the output object("Yalla.txt") the first element (0)
i++; //increase the element to get the next.
}
```

All of this should read from a file, and store it in another file. Couldnt compile because of bad path got a new mac idk how that works yet buut yeah let me know if something goes wrong
    readThis.close();
    output.close();
    }
    }

Comment: This is awesome, thank you but I'm getting an error. I'm getting an out of bounds exception. Index:11, Size:11. I am not aware of what this means. Do you know?